# Do the values above and below a Sigma in a summation have a name?

Tags: summation, terminology

As the title asks: do the numbers above and below a sigma have a specific technical name?

I am trying to describe an inefficiency in an algorithm, where the set of items used in the summation could be different, making the algorithm more efficient. However, I'd like to say what I have to say in the most professional way possible and not:

*the number below the sigma...*

Unless of course, they have no specific name.

Comment: I expect they're normally called the upper and lower limits of summation, as in integration. (Or the lowest index and the highest index, perhaps.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most commonly the lower and upper bound of the summation index. See, for instance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation.